# Return original value jquery / php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, reset-button

I am using this code to run my extra button. It changes original price value to custom value. Is it possible to click again on button named „afterclickbutton“ to get price with original value - meaning get regular price, and reset whole thing, so it could be possible to click again and get custom value, then click and get regular price value etc etc.?

> // Přidání bestpprice' vlastního pole
> $bestprice = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_bestprice', true);
>
> ```
> if( ! empty($bestprice) ):
>
> $bestprice = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $bestprice ) );
> $reg_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
> $range = wc_format_sale_price( $reg_price, $bestprice );
> ?>
> <!-- The button and hidden field --> 
> <div class="bestprice-wrapper"><br>
>     <a href="" class="get_bestprice button alt" id="get_bestprice"><?php _e('Aktivovat lepší cenu');?></a>
>     <input type="hidden" name="bestprice" id="bestprice" class="bestprice" value="" />
>   </div>
> <!-- The jQuery code --> 
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     (function($){
>         var b = '<?php echo $bestprice; ?>',
>             i = 'input[name=bestprice]',
>             p = 'p.price',
>             r = '<?php echo $range; ?>',
>             t = 'a#get_bestprice'
>             u = true;
>         $(t).click( function(e){
>             e.preventDefault();
>             if(u){
>                 $(p).html(r);  // Replacing price with the range
>                 $(i).val(b);  // Set the best price in hidden input field
>                 $(t).text(‚Activated'); // change button text
>                 $(t).removeClass('alt'); // Remove button 'alt' class for styling
>                                   $(t).removeClass('get_bestprice')
>                                           $(t).addClass(‚afterclickbutton')
>                                   u = false;   // Disable button
>
>
>             }
>         });
>     })(jQuery);
> </script>
> <?php
> endif; }
> ```

Comment: There's probably a better way, but I'd have the initial page draw store the "old" price somewhere else, in a hidden div perhaps, then recover that value when the user presses `afterclickbutton`, and set the button class back to `get_bestprice` so you can effectively toggle between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 2:

```
if( ! empty($bestprice) ):

$bestprice = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $bestprice ) );
$reg_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
$range = wc_format_sale_price( $reg_price, $bestprice );
?>
<!-- The button and hidden field --> 
<div class="bestprice-wrapper"><br>
    <a href="" class="get_bestprice button alt" id="get_bestprice"><?php _e('Aktivovat lepší cenu');?></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="bestprice" id="bestprice" class="bestprice" value="" />
  </div>
<!-- The jQuery code --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
        var b = '<?php echo $bestprice; ?>',
            o = $('p.price').clone().find('del').remove().end().text().trim().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, ''),
            i = 'input[name=bestprice]',
            p = 'p.price',
            r = '<?php echo $range; ?>',
            t = 'a#get_bestprice'
            u = true;
        $(t).click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(u){
                if ($(p).attr('type') == undefined){ $(p).attr('type','_regular_price') };
                if ($(`${p}[type="_best_price"]`).length == 0) {
                    $(p).hide().after(`<p class="price" type="_best_price">${r}</p>`); // add best price and hide regulare
                }else{
                    $(`${p}[type="_regular_price"]`).hide();
                    $(`${p}[type="_best_price"]`).show();
                }
                //$(p).html(r);  // Replacing price with the range
                $(i).val(b);  // Set the best price in hidden input field
                $(t).text('Activated') // change button text
                .removeClass('alt get_bestprice') // Remove button 'alt' class for styling
                .addClass('afterclickbutton');
                u = false;   // Disable button
            }else{
                $(`${p}[type="_best_price"]`).hide();
                $(`${p}[type="_regular_price"]`).show();
                $(i).val(o);
                $(t).text('Active best price')
                .addClass('alt get_bestprice')
                .removeClass('afterclickbutton');
                u = true; 
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
endif; }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. unfortunately this tip did not work. I tried to replace 'original_value' with '_get_regular_price' which is a class that gives the classic price of the product in the product price setting in woocommerce. Unfortunately, even with this change, the price did not return and always remained at the "best price", as can be seen in this link: http://testwpcena.atwebpages.com/product/akzm-8480-ix/

Comment: Use this update, last script before that, is has problem.

Comment: U are AMAZING man :) thank you

Comment: Hi, i just saw this''JQuery add attribute function is not working''where u helped to solve this problem. And what I think about is-is it possible to implement something like this to my btn?What I would like to achieve is to have an option for customers to choose between betterprice and free gift with bestprice button (from this topic) for gifts Im using plugin 'PW Woocommerce Advanced Gift Rules by Proword‘ -I can provide data from main.php etc. example page http://testwpcena.atwebpages.com/product/akzm-8480-ix/ Is it possible to add function to button for disable enable gifts? @YounesBennour

Comment: If it could be done - to i would totally understand if you would any payment for this - if you could help me, you can contact me on vasek.jokl@gmail.com